# expected 'while' or expected '}' Answered before yes, but I can't fix it myself

Tags: c++

I have already checked all the other questions but I just can't fix it.. I am a nuub at coding.
I don't know why it says it needs a while or where to put it, and it gives the wrong answer for the LOCS function also is there anything i can do about the default pointer warning. this is just a start i will be extending this later so it would be a big help and i have tried while and closing brackets everywhere lol

Btw if anyone can tell me how I can use the input as decision as you can see I am using 1 and 2, but If I could use permanent and casual that would be great.

```
// Calculate an employee's weekly salary
// Use a do while loop, and an if else statement to have user input data and display the correct values

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //Declaring the constant variables
    const double BONUS_RATE = 5.0;

    //Declaring the variables
    int hours;
    int sales;
    int Status;

    string permanent, casual, Name, status, result, employee;

    double rate, sale_bonus, netPay, gross;



    //set decimal point to 2 positions
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    //Display name
    cout << "Calculate an employee's weekly salary\n\n";

    //Do while loop to get hourly rate
    do {


        cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        cin >> Name;

        cout << "Please enter 1 if employee is permanent or 2 if casual: ";
        cin >> Status;

        Status = 0;
        while (Status < 1 || Status > 2);

        if (Status = 1)
        {

            cout << "Permanent employees have a fixed salary of $1000 per week" << endl;

            sales = 0;
            (sales < 1 || sales > 10);

            cout << "If any please enter how many sales employee made this week:";
            cin >> sales;

            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = 1000 + sale_bonus;

            cout << endl;

            cout
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;

        }
        else if (Status = 2) {



            cout << "Casual employee's hourly rate is $15";
            rate = 15.00;
            cout << endl;



            //while loop for hours

            hours = 0;
            while (hours < 1 || hours > 60)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many hours you have worked this week:" << endl;
                cout << "Minimum hours is 1" << endl;
                cout << "Maximum hours are 60" << endl;
                cout << "Enter hours worked: ";

                cin >> hours;

            }

            //while loop for bonus

            sales = 0;
            while (sales < 1 || sales > 10)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many sales you made this week:";
                cin >> sales;
            }

            //Calculate pay


            gross = hours * rate;
            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = gross + sale_bonus;

            //Display the results
            cout << endl
                << "Hourly Rate:  \t" << rate << endl
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need `while` after the closing brace that matches the opening one after `do`. As in, `do { ... } while (some_condition};` Count your braces.

Comment: Yes, close the do while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //Declaring the constant variables
    const double BONUS_RATE = 5.0;

    //Declaring the variables
    int hours;
    int sales;
    int Status;

    string permanent, casual, Name, status, result, employee;

    double rate, sale_bonus, netPay, gross;



    //set decimal point to 2 positions
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    //Display name
    cout << "Calculate an employee's weekly salary\n\n";

    //Do while loop to get hourly rate
    do {


        cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        cin >> Name;

        cout << "Please enter 1 if employee is permanent or 2 if casual: ";
        cin >> Status;

   } while (Status < 1 || Status > 2); // add while after do block with }

        if (Status == 1)// use '==' equality check not '=' .
        {

            cout << "Permanent employees have a fixed salary of $1000 per week" << endl;

            sales = 0;
            (sales < 1 || sales > 10);

            cout << "If any please enter how many sales employee made this week:";
            cin >> sales;

            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = 1000 + sale_bonus;

            cout << endl;

            cout
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;

        }
        else if (Status == 2) { // use '==' equality check not '=' .



            cout << "Casual employee's hourly rate is $15";
            rate = 15.00;
            cout << endl;



            //while loop for hours

            hours = 0;
            while (hours < 1 || hours > 60)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many hours you have worked this week:" << endl;
                cout << "Minimum hours is 1" << endl;
                cout << "Maximum hours are 60" << endl;
                cout << "Enter hours worked: ";

                cin >> hours;

            }

            //while loop for bonus

            sales = 0;
            while (sales < 1 || sales > 10)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many sales you made this week:";
                cin >> sales;
            }

            //Calculate pay


            gross = hours * rate;
            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = gross + sale_bonus;

            //Display the results
            cout << endl
                << "Hourly Rate:  \t" << rate << endl
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;


        }


}
```

I have made the suitable changes :

> Use `==` to check equality instead of `=` operator!
>
> Syntax of do while : `do { //code... } while(condition)`.
>
> The while must follow the do after closing the block!

### Your Mistake

the main mistake is you have not close the do while loop, ask in comment for more clarification!
PS. I recommend you first copy my code and then run, and then analyse the issue!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code this will work**

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
void main()
{
    //Declaring the constant variables
    const double BONUS_RATE = 5.0;

    //Declaring the variables
    int hours;
    int sales;
    int Status;

    string permanent, casual, Name, status, result, employee;

    double rate, sale_bonus, netPay, gross;



    //set decimal point to 2 positions
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    //Display name
    cout << "Calculate an employee's weekly salary\n\n";

    //Do while loop to get hourly rate
    while(1){


        cout << "Enter employee name: ";
        cin >> Name;

        cout << "Please enter 1 if employee is permanent or 2 if casual: ";
        cin >> Status;

        Status = 0;
        while (Status < 1 || Status > 2);

        if (Status = 1)
        {

            cout << "Permanent employees have a fixed salary of $1000 per week" << endl;

            sales = 0;
            (sales < 1 || sales > 10);

            cout << "If any please enter how many sales employee made this week:";
            cin >> sales;

            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = 1000 + sale_bonus;

            cout << endl;

            cout
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;

        }
        else if (Status = 2) {



            cout << "Casual employee's hourly rate is $15";
            rate = 15.00;
            cout << endl;



            //while loop for hours

            hours = 0;
            while (hours < 1 || hours > 60)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many hours you have worked this week:" << endl;
                cout << "Minimum hours is 1" << endl;
                cout << "Maximum hours are 60" << endl;
                cout << "Enter hours worked: ";

                cin >> hours;

            }

            //while loop for bonus

            sales = 0;
            while (sales < 1 || sales > 10)
            {
                cout << "Please enter how many sales you made this week:";
                cin >> sales;
            }

            //Calculate pay


            gross = hours * rate;
            sale_bonus = sales * BONUS_RATE;
            netPay = gross + sale_bonus;

            //Display the results
            cout << endl
                << "Hourly Rate:  \t" << rate << endl
                << "Hours Worked: \t" << hours << endl
                << "Gross Pay:  \t" << gross << endl
                << "Net Pay  \t" << netPay << endl;


        }

    }

}
```